# Change date format from dd-mm-yy to ddmmyy

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 dates values as Start-date & End-date. I enter these dates using a JQuery Date Picker. The format in the text boxes is `dd-mm-yy`. Now what I want is to convert the dates to `ddmmyy` format, without any '`-`' or '`/`' or '`\`'. I will execute this within a function when the submit button of my HTML page clicked.

I use this format is because the dates are using in Google Analytic Dashboard with a JSON web service.

Comment: Have you looked up “javascript remove characters from string”?

Comment: Converts a date object to the one you want: http://jsfiddle.net/nj94D/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you can use string split method also.

check the working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9q7H8/).

```
var yourDate = "11-12-2014";
getDate(yourDate);

function getDate(yourDate){
    var date = yourDate.toString();
    var divide = date.split('-');
    var newDate = divide[0]+divide[1]+divide[2];
    alert(newDate);
}
```

Comment: actually the answer was mine :) Anyway glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
document.getElementById([your-target]).value = newDate.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");
```

Comment: Or `...replace(/\D/g,'')`. :-)

Comment: My statement is like this                                          var strStartDate = document.getElementById("from_date").value;                            If I edit the statement as the below it gave me an error.             var strStartDate = document.getElementById("from_date").value = newDate.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ""); So how am I going to use that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use datepicker to format the date for you :

```
var myDate = '12-06-2014';
var myNewDate =  $.datepicker.formatDate('ddmmyy', $.datepicker.parseDate( 'dd-mm-yy', myDate ) );
alert (myNewDate);
```

achieves everything on one line and easily adapted for other formats should you need.

to reflect your actual code, you would write:

```
var myDate = document.getElementById("from_date").value;
var strStartDate =  $.datepicker.formatDate('ddmmyy', $.datepicker.parseDate( 'dd-mm-yy', myDate ) );
```

Jon

Comment: I have this code snippet to add the dates from the datepicker. `$("#to_date").datepicker({  maxDate: new Date(),dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd"});
     $("#from_date").datepicker({  maxDate: new Date(),dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd"});` **Now how am I suppose to use your code snippet to adopt with my code?**