# set right dateformat with jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to set the the date format to `'dd-mm-yy'`

Here is my script, but this doesn't seem to work. It still displays the standard `'mm-dd-yy'`

What I'm I doing wrong. Here is my script:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#datepickerStartDate").datepicker();
        $("#format").change(function () {
            $("#datepickerStartDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).val();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can check the [http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats] for details on formatting date. The change in your code would be as below : `$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", $( this ).val() );`. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm a newbie with jQuery. I don't really understand the example code you send. If I put it in my code, where should I set the proper format I want to use?

Comment: @user3228992 something like http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/7z666zq7/ ?

Comment: Nice bruvo, Ah funny that and for share @IrvinDominin see the difference http://jsfiddle.net/pm5b24fh/ - apparently if you add the format after `datepicker` bind it adds `dd/mm/yy` fixed with demo 2 in my post by binding `click` event. Thought i would share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/66qot0ye/)** or **[Demo 2 working here](http://jsfiddle.net/pm5b24fh/)**

I have added html and the sample, if you strictly aim for `dd-mm-yy` the checkout another SO link below.

- [Change date format from dd-mm-yy to ddmmyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924926/change-date-format-from-dd-mm-yy-to-ddmmyy)

Hope rest help your need `:)`

**code sample**

```
$(function(){

    $('#thedate').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        altField: '#thealtdate',
        altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for this:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#datepickerStartDate").datepicker();
        $("#format").change(function () {
            $( "#datepickerStartDate" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", 'dd-mm-yy' );
        });
    });
</script>
```

After your comment, I think you are actually looking for this:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#datepickerStartDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" });
    });
</script>
```

If not, please let me know exactly what you want to achieve with which html-elements.

Comment: Thank you. But my datepicker still displays in the format `'mm-dd-yy'`
Can't understand why?